# how to Listview Refresh after Delete an item on Button Click event in android?

Tags: android, listview, refresh

I want to delete an item from Listview, and at a time Refresh Listview after deleting an item. How to possible?

I am using get all item using JSON Parsing from database and delete an selected an item on click of button. delete successfully from database but Listview not refresh at a time. how to do?

I am using Json Parsing. not local database.

In This case, How to refresh Listview when Deleting Item?
please Guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

My Code is,
Detail.java File

```
public class Detail extends Activity {
    ListView lstDetail = null;
    /** String */
    String urlGetDetailData = null;

    /** Declare another variable for Listview */
    Adapter1 adapter1 = null;
    ArrayList<Detail> myList = new ArrayList<Detail>();
    /** Hashmap for ListView */
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = null;

    /** JSON Node names */
    public static final String TAG_MEMBER_ID = "mem_id";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USER_ID = "userid";
    public static final String TAG_STATUS = "Status";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onCreateActivity(R.layout.detail);

        initializeWidgets();
    }

    private void initializeWidgets() {
        /** ListView */
        lstDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDetail);

        urlGetDetailData = "http://example.com/getdata.php?id="
                + strId;

        new GetDetailData().execute();
        myList.remove(position);
        Adapter1.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetDetailData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        JSONObject jsonobject;
        JSONArray jsonarray;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlGetDetailData);

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects

                    map.put("mem_id", String.valueOf(jsonobject
                            .getString(TAG_MEMBER_ID)));
                    map.put("id",
                            jsonobject.getString(TAG_ID));

                    map.put("userid", jsonobject.getString(TAG_USER_ID));
                    map.put("Status", jsonobject.getString(TAG_STATUS));

                    dataList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (dataList.size() != 0) {
                lstDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Adapter1 = new Adapter1(Detail.this,
                        dataList);
                lstDetail.setAdapter(Adapter1);
            } else {
                lstDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Adapter Class is,
Adapter1.java File

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrData = null;
    Context context = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    HashMap<String, String> getDetailData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /** String */
    String strMemberId = null, urlDelete = null;

    /** Constructor */
    public Adapter1(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrData) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrData  = arrData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            getData = arrData.get(position);

            /** Initialize Widgets */

            viewHolder.imgCancel = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgCancel);

            viewHolder.imgCancel
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            strMemberId = arrData.get(
                                    position).get(
                                    Detail.TAG_MEMBER_ID);
                            urlDelete = "http://example.com/delete.php?mem_id="
                                    + strMemberId;
                            new DeleteComments().execute();
                        }
                    });

            /** TextView */
            viewHolder.txtMemberId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtMemberId);
            viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtId);

            viewHolder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

            /** Set Value */


            viewHolder.txtMemberId.setText(getDetailData 
                    .get(Detail.TAG_MEMBER_ID));
            viewHolder.txtId.setText(getDetailData
                    .get(Detail.TAG_ID));

            viewHolder.txtDesc.setText(getDetailData
                    .get(Detail.TAG_STATUS));

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    /** ViewHolder Class */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgCancel = null;
        TextView txtMemberId = null, txtId = null,txtDesc = null;
    }

    public class DeleteComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlDelete,
                    ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response : delete join comments", ">" + jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        };
    }
}
```

detail.xml File is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstDetail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="111" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMemberId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtUserEventId"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtUserEventId"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="222" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: in your custom adapter call this.notifyDataSetChanged(); where you are performing delete functionality and deleting that element from arrayList which is set to that adapter

Comment: @Shrinivas Please Update in my code becuase This code work succesfully remaining Listview Refresh... Where is updatein my code.

Comment: Have you used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: @Reena Just add `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `postexecute`.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I am using delete Item from database successfully then after using Like this arrayListDetailData.remove(position);        DetailAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); for delete item from listview then delete last item not selected item from Listview. Means delete from last in listview. plz help me. how to do delete selected item from listview item?

Comment: @Yugesh I am using delete Item from database successfully then after using Like this arrayListDetailData.remove(position); DetailAdapter.this.notifyDataSetCha‌​nged(); for delete item from listview then delete last item not selected item from Listview. Means delete from last in listview. plz help me. how to do delete selected item from listview item? See my Updated Question

Comment: @Reena you want to select the list items 2 to max.you have one delete button to delete all selected items in list view am right.

Comment: @Yugesh No Suppose I have 10 Items in My Listview then I want to delete Item No.4. so Actually delete Item No.4 But In my case delete Item No.10. Its delete starting from Last. Then After Delete Item No.9 etc. Delete Button Available for every item separetly... If i Click on Delete Button on Item No.5 then delete Item No.5 etc.

Comment: @Reena okay.when you click cancel it execute asyc task to delete the row am right.

Comment: @Reena you got the solution.

Comment: @Yugesh Yes. But Delete Successfully from Database only issue is in Listview. and also get Correct Position when Click on imgCancel Button but delete only Last Item from Listview not selected Item.and Also i am using arrData.remove(position); notifyDataSetChanged(); after delete item from database.

Comment: @Reena declare one `int pos;` globally in this base adapter class, when you click cancel button set `pos = position` in `postexecute arrData.remove(pos);notifyDataSetChanged();` try this.

Comment: @Yugesh I can try it also but nothing change

Comment: @Reena put log to get position at the time of onclick and before `arrData.remove(pos)` from list to check get correct position or not.

Comment: @Yugesh Yes I got the Current Position Correctly. and put this code in post excute of DeleteComments().execute class.arrData.remove(curpos);
 Adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); Am I Right? If yes then what is wrong in this code?

Comment: @Reena okay.you got the current position correctly in both click event and post executive am right.

Comment: @Yugesh Yes Exactly...

Comment: can any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your custom adapter call `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` where you are performing delete functionality and deleting that element from arrayList which is set to that adapter

Comment: where you are performing delete functionality and deleting that element from arrayList which is set to that adapter

Comment: delete record directly from table(using JSON Parsing). not delete record from arrayList.

Comment: @Reena I agree but you have to remove that record from the ArrayList too that you have set to your adapter if you know which record it is you can use ArrayList.remove(index); and then use notifyDataSetChanged(); :)

Comment: I am using delete Item from database successfully then after using Like this arrayListDetailData.remove(position); DetailAdapter.this.notifyDataSetCha‌​nged(‌​); for delete item from listview then delete last item not selected item from Listview. Means delete from last in listview. plz help me. how to do delete selected item from listview item? See my Updated Question .

Comment: use ur listView.setOnItemClickListener() and then in that onItemClickListener you will get the position use that position for removing the element from the arrayList using arrayList.remove(position); and then use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); :)

Comment: Noon But If I click on Delete Button then delete the Item not delete Click on ListView clickListener.

Comment: Oh sorry write your button onClickListener in fetView in that you get the position so use that to remove that item :)

Comment: I have also Edit My Question Plese see it and tell me where is Change in My code.

Comment: How to do? How to possible it?

Comment: If I click on delete Button for selected Item then it's item delete Successfully database but In Listview, delete last Item not selected Item.

Comment: Please see one more answer given by me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing delete action, in that function only call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged again.So it refr
on delete action fetch the data once again and then again call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged it will work

Comment: But i am writing delete action in Adapter class so I cant write adapter.notifyDataSetChanged. where is change in my code?

Comment: Ok I have merge both class activity and adapter. then after i put the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in in postExecute in DeleteComments but not any change.

Comment: @Reena You dont have to merge you classes , in delete action in your custom adapter just write notifyDataSetChanged(); thats it

Answer (score 0):

First of all Put you adapter code in Details.java class

then change this,

```
public class DeleteComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlDelete,
                    ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response : delete join comments", ">" + jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Adapter1.remove(Adapter1.getItem(position));
        };
    }
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I am using delete Item from database successfully then after using Like this arrayListDetailData.remove(position); DetailAdapter.this.notifyDataSetCha‌​nged(); for delete item from listview then delete last item not selected item from Listview. Means delete from last in listview. plz help me. how to do delete selected item from listview item? see my Updated Question

Comment: can you help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                getData = arrData.get(position);

                /** Initialize Widgets */

                viewHolder.imgCancel = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgCancel);

                viewHolder.imgCancel
                        .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                strMemberId = arrData.get(
                                        position).get(
                                        Detail.TAG_MEMBER_ID);
                                urlDelete = "http://example.com/delete.php?mem_id="
                                        + strMemberId;
                                new DeleteComments().execute();
                            }
                        });

                /** TextView */
                viewHolder.txtMemberId = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtMemberId);
                viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtId);

                viewHolder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

                /** Set Value */


                viewHolder.txtMemberId.setText(getDetailData 
                        .get(Detail.TAG_MEMBER_ID));
                viewHolder.txtId.setText(getDetailData
                        .get(Detail.TAG_ID));

                viewHolder.txtDesc.setText(getDetailData
                        .get(Detail.TAG_STATUS));

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
bDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                arrData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged():
            }

});


            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I have Performing delete Action on  viewHolder.imgCancel Button. and I put the  viewHolder.imgCancel Button code is Last and set The also  arrData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged(); but Remove again Last Record. Coreect position is get. but remove last record

Comment: Please add line Log.i("position", ""+ position) and tell me what is the position you are getting in logcat is it the same position you want to remove

Answer (score 0):

Why make it that complicated?

Just call `remove(Obj);` in `OnClickListener` of your customized adapter `Adapter1`'s. And `notifyDataSetChanged` will be called in removed method too.