# Deleting listview item from database

Tags: android, listview

I am deleting the title 2 list item item

[image]

But the last title gets deleted that is the title 8 gets deleted

[image]

When I then go back to the previous screen and reopen the list. The correct that is the 2nd item title 2 had been deleted.

[image]

Here is the DataAdapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String a[];
Context ctx;
View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
MyDBHandler dbHelper;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
ArrayList<Calendars> arrayList;

public DataAdapter(Context reminderList, ArrayList<Calendars> arrayList, MyDBHandler dbHelper) {
    this.ctx = reminderList;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
}

public void Swap(ArrayList<Calendars> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList.clear();
    this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e("arraylist", arrayList.toString());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_record, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datelist);
        holder.timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timelist);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titlelist);
        holder.idTextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idlist);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deletelist);
        holder.dateTextView.setText(arrayList.get(position).get_reminderdate());
        holder.timeTextView.setText(arrayList.get(position).get_remindertime());
        holder.titleTextView.setText(arrayList.get(position).get_remindertitle());
        holder.idTextview.setText(arrayList.get(position).get_id() + "");
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                adb.setTitle("Delete");
                adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete  this reminder?");
                //final int positionToRemove = view.getId();
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

                adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dbHelper.remove(arrayList.get(position).get_id());
                        Log.e("position", position + "");

                        arrayList.remove(position);
                        arrayList = dbHelper.databaseToArrayList();
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                        //Swap(dbHelper.databaseToArrayList());


                    }
                });
                adb.show();
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView titleTextView, dateTextView, timeTextView, idTextview;
    Button deleteButton;
}
}
```

Here is the ListActivity

```
public class ReminderList extends ActionBarActivity {
Calendars calendars;
Button deleteButton;
private MyDBHandler dbHelper;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<Calendars> arrayList;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

int pos;
DataAdapter dataAdapter;

final String[] from = new String[]{MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_TITLE,
        MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_DATE, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_TIME, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID,
        MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_DESCRIPTION, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_SNOOZE, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_REMINDER_REPEAT, MyDBHandler.COLUMN_ID};

final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.titlelist, R.id.datelist, R.id.timelist, R.id.idlist,
        R.id.descriptionlist, R.id.snoozelist, R.id.repeatlist, R.id.deletelist};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder_list);
    deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deletelist);
    // adapter=new DataAdapter(ReminderList.this,from);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    arrayList = new ArrayList<Calendars>();
    dbHelper = new MyDBHandler(this);
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetch();
    arrayList = dbHelper.databaseToArrayList();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, arrayList, dbHelper);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {

            String title = arrayList.get(position).get_remindertitle();
            Log.d("title", title);
            String date = arrayList.get(position).get_reminderdate();
            String time = arrayList.get(position).get_remindertime();
            String id = arrayList.get(position).get_id() + "";
            String description = arrayList.get(position).get_reminderdescription();
            String snooze = arrayList.get(position).get_remindersnooze();
            String repeat = arrayList.get(position).get_reminderrepeat();

            Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);

            modify_intent.putExtra("id", id);
            modify_intent.putExtra("title", title);
            modify_intent.putExtra("time", time);
            modify_intent.putExtra("date", date);
            modify_intent.putExtra("description", description);
            modify_intent.putExtra("snooze", snooze);
            modify_intent.putExtra("repeat", repeat);

            startActivity(modify_intent);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidateViews();
        }
    });
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.add_record: {
            Intent add_mem = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(add_mem);

        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

DatabasetoArraylist function

```
    public ArrayList<Calendars> databaseToArrayList() {

    ArrayList<Calendars> arrayList = new ArrayList();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDER;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_reminderdate")) != null) {

            Calendars calendars = new Calendars();
            calendars.set_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
            calendars.set_reminderdate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_DATE)));
            calendars.set_remindertime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_TIME)));
            calendars.set_remindertitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_TITLE)));
            calendars.set_reminderdescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_DESCRIPTION)));
            calendars.set_reminderrepeat(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_REPEAT)));
            calendars.set_remindersnooze(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_REMINDER_SNOOZE)));

            arrayList.add(calendars);
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return arrayList;

}
```

Comment: in adapter  notifyDataSetInvalidated(); this should not be there as Changed means the data set changed. Individual items updated, or items were added or removed. Invalidated means the data source is no longer available.have you tried to remove this

Comment: I just removed notifyDataSetInvalidated(); Still the same result @BhushanRaut

Comment: NotifyDataSetInvalidated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148474/how-to-listview-refresh-after-delete-an-item-on-button-click-event-in-android

Comment: sorry but nothing is there related to NotifyDataSetInvalidated in above post

Comment: General tip: those images are rather large, and readers may feel the question is so long they give up with it. You may find you get more answers if you make images a bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView() method of adapter by below code:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final Calendars calendars = arrayList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_record, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datelist);
        holder.timeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timelist);
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titlelist);
        holder.idTextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idlist);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deletelist);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else
   {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

    holder.dateTextView.setText(calendars.get_reminderdate());
    holder.timeTextView.setText(calendars.get_remindertime());
    holder.titleTextView.setText(calendars.get_remindertitle());
    holder.idTextview.setText(calendars.get_id() + "");

    holder.deleteButton.setTag(calendars);
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
            adb.setTitle("Delete");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete  this reminder?");
            //final int positionToRemove = view.getId();
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    final selectedCalendar = (Calendars) holder.deleteButton.getTag();

                    dbHelper.remove(selectedCalendar.get_id());
                    arrayList = dbHelper.databaseToArrayList();
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //Swap(dbHelper.databaseToArrayList());

                }
            });
        adb.show();
        }
    });
}
return convertView;
}
```